# Change Position Marker Color in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, caret

I was wondering how to change the color of the position marker (the blinking I) in a JTextArea. The reason I want to do this is because I'm going to have a GUI with a black background, and green text (old terminal style). I want a white or green position marker. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call [`textArea.setCaretColor(Color.WHITE);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setCaretColor%28java.awt.Color%29) method.